# QGIS Duplicate Labels still appearing despite suggested changes. Do i need to do an expression?

Tags: qgis, labeling, query, expression, duplication

I have one field called Streets. In Streets there are road beds with suffix as Pkwy, Street, Avenue, Expressway and so on.

I also want to label some of these road beds.

[image]

In Layer styling under placement on Repeat i clicked No repeat, and in rendering I clicked Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels?

What do i need to do to remove these duplicates and in their place label some other streets from the view below?

Comment: One possible method is to **dissolve** all features which make up the same street. Then the label would only appear once.

Comment: I was wondering if i can avoid that because these files got to come from a certain source.

Comment: if your dataset is not too large you can create a query to apply Joseph's proposal ... meaning you don't modify your original data.

Comment: You could try something like the expression I explained here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299789/107424. Never tested the label positioning with lines (roads) though.

Comment: I don't know when i add it into Label with it says the Expression is invalid. I changed the column names. The question does seem to resemble mine.