# QGIS - Duplicate Labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, point

I have a dataset of points with data at different depths:

e.g as a csv file as follows:

> "ID","DEPTH","VALUE"
>
> "BH01","0.5","10"
>
> "BH01","2.0","50"

There will be multiple points with the same ID but different depths - how can I make QGIS only label the "ID" once? Have been banging my head with this for a while and can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Are you aware that duplicate geometries aren't best practice? If so, why did you choose to use them? Furthermore, how do you decide which value to use for a label, or which column would you want to use for a label?

Comment: Check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299788/how-to-label-only-one-feature-in-qgis-without-editing-layers-when-several-have-t

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of simple solutions. I'm assuming points with the same ID are at nearly the same location.

1. If the points with the same ID are supposed to be at the same location, try snapping them to *exactly* the same location with the one of the snap tools (`snap geometries to layer` or `snap points to points`).

   [image]

   When two points are in exactly the same place QGIS will usually only label one of them.

   [image]
2. Use the point cluster rendering symbology type. This generates a symbol with two layers: a point marker and a font marker. Change the font marker portion of the symbol to display the ID field.

   [image]

It's worth noting (as Erik pointed out in the comments above) that duplicate geometries are not a best practice. It might be better to rearrange your data to have a single point at each location, and multiple depth fields for each point, eg "Depth1" "Depth2" "Depth3" etc. The snapping tools and the `aggregate` tools might be helpful for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied / pasted the items, their UID or ID, that you use to anchor the field through their attribute table, would be the same.

Solution: Using the field calculator, re-populate the null fields in the ID or UID that you use to anchor your label's, to create a separate (and therefore no longer duplicated) field. Use @row_number to re-number and give all fields a unique identifier.