# Creating convex hull by expression by aggregating points

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, centroids, convex-hull

I would like to recieve the centroid of a convex hull of a group of points in a layer, grouped by its name. This needs to be done by expressions, available in QGIS 3.4. E.g. I have this list of points:

```
id,name
1,abc
2,abc
3,def
4,def
5,abc
6,def
7,geh
8,jkl
```

I want to receive the centroids of

1. abc
2. def
3. geh
4. jkl

At least the first two should work as there are minimum 3 points. I was trying this expression:

```
centroid(convex_hull(collect($geometry,group_by:="name")))
```

In preview it does not throw back any errors. It actually delivers the correct geometry. But only in preview.

[image]

If I try to use this expression as e.g. Labelposition, it does not display any labels at all. If I try to use this expression in `geometry by expression` tool it throws back this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS34~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\GeometryByExpression.py",
>   line 124, in processFeature self.tr('Evaluation error:
>   {0}').format(self.expression.evalErrorString()))
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: Evaluation error: Cannot use aggregate function in this context

Is there a way to recieve the centroid of a convex hull of grouped points using QGIS 3.4 expressions?

Comment: Hi MrXsquared, in labels placement, Data Defined, `x(centroid(convex_hull(collect($geometry,group_by:="name"))))` and `y(centroid(convex_hull(collect($geometry,group_by:="name"))))`, returns labels for each group name in the centroid of the convex hull collected. I don't know if it is creating a lot of labels one over the other, because the expression must be evaluated against each feature. But there are not errors.

Comment: About the geometry by expression algorithm, if you collect the geometries before (with Collect algorithm) you will not find problems in return the centroid of the convex hull for each feature.

Comment: Multiple labels shouldnt be an issue because they were filtered before using https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299789/107424. Just re-tried on my private computer with a different dataset and I cannot reproduce the label-position-issue. Must be something else then. However, using geometry by expression, the same error occurs. Can you explain your second comment a little further? Not sure if I understand correctly.

Comment: since the expression is re-evaluated for every feature, try making "name" the `filter` instead of the `group_by` parameter.

Comment: @MrXsquared, maybe the problem is produced trying to create convex hull of one-part or two-parts multipoint features, I have tested with many points for each name. About the _Geometry by expression_ algorithm, I see the same error. But if I run a _Collect_ algorithm against the layer, and then a _Geometry by expression_ with `centroid(convex_hull($geometry))` for the _Collected_ layer, it works fine.

Comment: Thats a good point @GabrielDeLuca Will see if I can find a one-step alternative to overcome this issue.