# How do I give one label to two points?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am making a map where I want to label two points with only one label. How can I do that? I've attached the image of my map.

[image]

Comment: I know you are using QGIS but in ArcGIS you would dissolve the point by the field that has the label values. Then label them and remove duplicates. That may give you insight on what to do in Q.

Comment: This would work in QGIS as well. However, two shortcomings to consider: 1. this approach is static, if you add or change geometries, you have to dissolve again. 2. Dissolving, you loose information. The solution I proposed overcomes these problems: once set, it works automatically and dynamically, even when changing geometries, attributes etc. It also affects only visualization and does not change data. In the same way, you could also hide symbolization (point rendering).

Comment: Check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299788/labeling-only-one-duplicate-attribute-in-qgis-without-editing-original-data

Answer (score 11):

A different aproach (than @Babel's) is to use the geometry generator which is available also in the label-engine. Just collect the geometries with the same name, building a multipoint geometry and then using the boundingbox to label all points with the same name with one Label:

[image]

The expression is (where "name" is the id for same objects which should be labeled together):

```
bounds(collect($geometry, group_by:="name"))
```

To make callouts to all points I used also the geometry generator for symbols. The labelpositions are stored in the auxiliary storage and can be used then to produce the callouts to all parts with the expression:

```
make_line($geometry,
  make_point( "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx" , 
            "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony") 
          )
```

[image]

Comment: A nice solution, indeed!

Comment: Thank you so much! Both @Babel and eurojam ! I got it to work on my project now! However now my callouts only reached one of the points where the label is assigned to two points, how did you make two callouts?

Comment: see the edited answer above.

Answer (score 3):

In the label settings, go  to the last tab called `rendering` and next to `show label` select data driven override and select `edit` (see screenshot below). Paste the following expression (`overlay_nearest()` function is [available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core), `array_min()` [since QGIS 3.18](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/index.html#feature-support-for-min-max-majority-sum-mean-and-median-functions-on-numerical-arrays)). It returns true (=show label) only if the point has a certain minimum distance (change that manually, see below) from it's nearest neighbor:

```
if (
    array_length (
        overlay_nearest( 
            @layer, 
            $geometry, 
            max_distance:=10000
        )
    ) >0,
    if (
        $id > array_min(
            overlay_nearest( 
                @layer, 
                $id,
                max_distance:=10000,
                limit:=100
            )
        ),
        0,
        1
    ),
    1
)
```

You can change the `max_distance:=10000` in line 6: only if points are closer to each other than this distance will labels be skipped. If two or more points are closer than this distance, still one (but **just one**) label will be rendered: the one of the point with the smallest `id` value in this group (cluster od points).

*Screenshot: as you see, where points are "clustered" (closer than 10.000 m), only one label is retained. Points a bit farther away will be labeled, however. For each of the three name, you have 3 "clusters" of points close together that illustrate how the expression works: in each cluster, only one point is labeled:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you! However it gives me some errors: 

Function is not known
syntax error, unexpected COMMA, expecting end of file
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end of file
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end of file

Can you help me with those?

Comment: What QGIS version do you use? This expression works with the current version 3.18. `array_min` function was only introduced in this latest release. Will update my answer accordingly.