# Give one symbol to several points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, labeling, symbology, expression

Without editing original data, I want to display a single symbol in the center for points which has identical attributes. I have an area with nine basements. To each basement belong several points. I've attached the image of my map:

[image: area with basements]

For labeling, I successfully used the `centroid ()` expression and the geometry generator:
[image]

I have not been able to transfer `centroid` expression to the symbols yet. Instead I used the code of MrXsquared to create a symbol for each basement
([Labeling only one duplicate attribute without editing original data in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299788/labeling-only-one-duplicate-attribute-without-editing-original-data-in-qgis)).
[image]

```
Case When array_find(array_agg( "id" ,group_by:= "gehoert_zu",filter:= "Ansicht" LIKE 'Draufsicht'),attribute($currentfeature,'id')) = 0 Then "gehoert_zu" LIKE '%Keller%' and "Ansicht" LIKE 'Draufsicht' Else '' END
```

But it is not in the center, because only the first feature within the array gets a label.
[image: non-centered symbols]

Any idea on how to combine `array_agg()` and `centroid()`?

Comment: Why don't you use the same `centroid()` expression for the symbology?

Comment: I'd try with: A geometry generator that creates the centroids and then set each centroid's symbology using overrides (with expressions using its group), might be a bit tricky to get the group to the centroid geometries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following to get a centroid geometry:

```
centroid(
    collect(
        $geometry,
        group_by:= <Group by attribute(s)>,
        filter:= attribute( 
get_feature_by_id(<layer>,$id),<Group by attribute(s)>)
    )
)
```

[image]
You might need to adapt it to your data. I dummied up my points based on the original (numbered) polygons, using Random points inside polygons, and added a field/attribute to each point based on the polygon it was created from.

Original points in blue, centroids (of the blue points) in red.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tom. Great solution! Didn't now the geometry generator for symbol function.

Comment: One thing I'd note is that there are possibly simpler solutions - the Geometry Generator is powerful, but complex. Playing with the "Geometry by expression" tool can give you a better handle on how it works, as you can review the actual features created (and not just the symbols)!

Comment: Also, if it solves your problem, or was the most useful solution, remember to accept the answer.

Comment: Problem was solved by using geometry generator (like Tom Brennan said) and same ```geometry ()``` expression which i used for labeling (suggestion by Andre Geo).
 To control the position of individual markers or labels, a data defined override can be used. To do this, call Placement -> Offset x,y -> Field calculator. Example for basement 4: 
CASE WHEN "gehort_zu" = 'Keller 4' and "Ansicht" ='Draufsicht' THEN 0,6 END. This moves the label/symbol 6 units to the south.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same `geometry generator` expression to set the centroid symbol.

Create a new `categorized` symbology, select the group by variable (or expression in your case). Then, click on the symbol and change it to be a geometry generator and enter the centroid expression.

```
centroid(collect($geometry, group_by:="test"))
```

Go back, click `classify` and adjust the symbols as you wish.

If you want the same symbol for every centroid, just use the `single symbol` instead.

In the example below, the light gray points are from a copy of the original layer.
[image]

[image]