Preventing labels from being placed too close to other features in the same layer in QGIS
I am working on a QGIS project where I need to prevent labels from being placed too close to features within the same layer. My aim is not just to avoid label overlaps, but to ensure that labels are displayed only for features that are a certain distance apart from other features — considering the actual spatial distance between the features themselves.
In the project, I have multiple small polygons that share the same label (e.g., "07/08/2008"), as illustrated in the sample image (orange labels). These polygons span across an area of about 20,000 acres, and often the same label is repeated multiple times due to the presence of several small, single-part polygons with the same label.

What I’ve Tried:

I attempted to use the "Prevent label overlap" option, but while
it prevents label overlap, but it does not solve the issue of controlling the spatial distance between labels and features.
I also tried setting a limit with "Label max 100 features," but this method labels only the first 100 polygons, starting from right to left, which is not suitable for my needs.
I considered selecting only polygons with an area greater than X square meters, but this approach excludes small polygons that I still want to display.
I looked into the overlay_nearest() function, but I’m not sure how to effectively use it to filter out features based on their proximity to others.

Goal:
I would like to apply a filter or use expressions in QGIS to control label placement so that labels are shown only when features with the same label are at least a certain distance apart (e.g., 1 cm in the layout).
Additional Details:

I am using the latest LTR QGIS version (3.34) at this moment.
The issue involves several small polygons with the same label, so I
need a way to avoid displaying the same label too close to each other
by enforcing a minimum buffer or distance between them.


How about something like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/299789/107424?

Here is an approach using clusters. The idea is to first build a spatial cluster and then cluster these spatial clusters by attribute, so you end up having clusters based on spatial distance and attribute. Let me explain:

Run the "DBSCAN Clustering" geoalgorithm on your layer. Choose a maximum distance of your choice and a minimum cluster size as you like. This will add a new field called "CLUSTER_ID"

Now open the Field Calculator on this layer and add a new field, let's call it "CLUSTER2", use this expression for it:
CLUSTER_ID || '_' ||
array_find(array_agg($id),
array_sort(array_agg($id,"CLUSTER_ID",filter:="label"=attribute(@parent,'label') and "CLUSTER_ID"=attribute(@parent,'CLUSTER_ID')))[0]
)

To explain this expression: It concatenates the "CLUSTER_ID" field of the spatial cluster with an underscore with the new spatial-attribute cluster.
The new spatial-attribute cluster is built by this part of the expression:
array_sort(array_agg($id,"CLUSTER_ID",filter:="label"=attribute(@parent,'label') and "CLUSTER_ID"=attribute(@parent,'CLUSTER_ID')))[0]

It basically builds an array of all feature IDs for each feature in the layer where the "label" field equals the 'label' field of the parent feature and the "CLUSTER_ID" field equals the 'CLUSTER_ID' field of the parent feature. To construct a cluster of this array we need to sort it ascending and then only get the first feature id of it. This feature id will serve as our cluster id.

Now open your label settings and go to Rendering -> Data defined -> Show label and enter this expression:
array_min(array_agg($id,"CLUSTER2")) = $id

it will ensure that only one label of each cluster will be displayed

Define the label placement via Labels -> Placement -> Geometry Generator and use a position of your choice. In the following expression, the point nearest to the cluster centroid is labeled.
closest_point(collect_geometries(array_agg($geometry,"CLUSTER2")),centroid(collect_geometries(array_agg($geometry,"CLUSTER2"))))

you could also just use the centroid or whatever position you wish.
If you want you can now also draw callout lines to each feature. But to be honest I struggled with these and am not sure whether this will look good... For visualization purposes, I prefer to add convex hulls to each group.
Here is what it could look like. It is a little chaotic because I just generated random points with random label groups. So it will definitely look better in your case:

For visualization purposes, I added convex hulls. I used this expression for it:
buffer(convex_hull(buffer(collect_geometries(array_agg($geometry,"CLUSTER2")),1)),100)

Alternatively, you can also dissolve your layer based on "CLUSTER2" field. This may make some label settings easier to define.
Now you can extend the label settings to your needs.
In my example, the field "label" is similar to your date field. It serves as the attribute group field.


